# DATE_SUB() always returns 0 results

Tags: mysql, select

I am attempting to select all rows from a database table which are 2 weeks old.

The `date_updated` field is a unix timestamp, which is what I am using in the query.

Here is the query:

```
select * from `leads` where date_format(from_unixtime(date_updated), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(date_sub(now(), interval 2 week), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Why is this query returning 0 results every time despite the fact that there ARE 2 week old leads in the table?

Comment: Can you give us an sqlfiddle?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  My best guess is that your field isn't really a unix timestamp, as understood by MySQL.

Comment: I figured it out. The issue was that I was returning a class method before the query was even executed. Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update date_sub() in you query.Change your query by the following format.

```
    select * from `leads` where date_format(from_unixtime(date_updated), '%Y-%m-%d') = date_format(date_sub(now() - interval 2 week), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score -1):

For performances reasons I would calculate the dates before doing the query:

PHP:

```
$twoWeeksAgo = new DateTime('-2 weeks');

$twoWeeksAgo->setTime(0, 0, 0);
$startOfDay = $twoWeeksAgo->getTimestamp();

$twoWeeksAgo->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$endOfDay = $twoWeeksAgo->getTimestamp();

$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM leads 
          WHERE date_updated BETWEEN '$startOfDay' AND '$endOfDay'";
```

Comment: This is a great way to optimize and speed up the query. Thank you for this.